# Can't open the "Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS"-File on Ubuntu Live

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, live-usb

I tried to install Ubuntu on my PC so I can run Windows and Ubuntu.
I created the Live-USB with Rufus and always got the Errno 5 when I tried to install Ubuntu to my drive. I always deleted the partitions after a try didn't work.
I tried everything I found in forums to solve this problem and eventually I recreated the Live-USB with balenaetcher. Now the "Install or try" window doesn't open on startup and if I click on the "Install Ubuntu 20.04 LTS" icon on the desktop nothing happens.
I thought maybe it is installed now but all non-windows partions are empty and when I eject the USB stick I can't boot Ubuntu.

I created the partitions for Ubuntu on my HDD.
I have a SSD where I start Windows and a HDD where I have all my data.
I wanted to install Ubuntu on my SSD but I couldn't create a partition that is large enough because windows doesn't allow it in its partition manager so I tried to install it on my HDD

I did check the md5 hashes and they're exactly the same as on the ubuntu website.

**SOLUTION: MY USB-DRIVE WAS CORRUPTED**

Comment: Maybe there was an error when you downloaded the iso file. Please check it with md5sum. Rufus can do that. See also [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes).

Comment: @sudodus The md5sums are the same. So this isn't the problem.

Comment: That's good :-) 1. Can you try the USB drive in another computer? 2. Please tell us the brand name and model of the computer and of the graphics chip/card; 3.The following link and links from it may help: [help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick), partcularly https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick/bootUSB and [Why Doesn't a Bootable USB Boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1190764/why-doesnt-a-bootable-usb-boot/)

Comment: 1. Unfortunately I don't have another computer available;
2. Mainboard: ASUS ROG STRIX B350-F GAMING,
    Processor: AMD Ryzen 7 1800X,
    Graphics card: Radeon RX 580;
3. The problem is that it boots and Ubuntu Live works perfectly but when I click on the install icon on the desktop nothing happens.

Comment: That indicates a problem with the graphics driver. Try to add the [boot option](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389&p=13370808#post13370808) `nomodeset` in the grub menu. Later on you may find a proprietary driver for your graphics card.

Comment: If I add `nomodeset` I get [this error](https://imgur.com/a/anKQsVB) and after that all text disappears and the screen stays black until I manually restart my pc. 
If I instead add `amdgpu.dc=0`the first error doesn't appear and Ubuntu Live starts perfectly fine though the other errors are still displayed before the desktop appears and I still can't open the installer.
If I try to `fsck`sdc3, the terminal says that isuch a folder doesn't exist and also in the Disks application sdc3 doesn't exist.

Comment: So it is not only a problem with the graphics. I'm sorry, but I have no computer with a Ryzen CPU, and cannot help much. Let us hope that someone who knows will see your question and help you :-) -- If you want to check a file sysstem, you should specify the partition as `/dev/sdc3` (and in an Ubuntu system with sudo, for example: `sudo e2fsck -fc /dev/sdc3` to force checking and mark bad sectors (of partition #3 in drive c) so that they will not be used).

Comment: I could eventually try another usb drive and now everything works perfectly fine. Thanks for your help

Comment: You are welcome and thanks for telling us what was the problem and how you solved it :-)